# Spring data jpa: Add a where clause on a projection field

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try to use Spring data JPA projections with a condition on a joined column with no success.

Given the following classes :

```
interface CarProjection {
    String getName();
    List<String> getColorsLabel();   
}

class Car{
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    List<Color> colors;
}

class Color{
     String label;

     @ManyToOne
     Car car;
}
```

And the following repository method :

```
List<CarProjection> findAllBy();
```

Everythings works well and spring generates the following query :

```
[....] left outer join color colors1_ on car0_.id=colors1_.car_id
```

What I want to do is to add a where clause on this join, for instance :

```
[....] left outer join color colors1_ on (car0_.id=colors1_.car_id AND colors1_.location='EXTERIOR')
```

On the projection class, it would give something like :

```
interface CarProjection {
    String getName();
    @Where("label=='EXTERIOR'")
    List<String> getColorsLabel();   
}
```

I know I can use a spel expression in a @Value do this, but then spring will fetch all the columns of the entity instead of just the projected ones (open projection).

I also tried to combine a JPA specification with the projection in my repository :

```
List<CarProjection> findAllBy(Specification<CarProjection> specification);
```

But it seems we cannot mix specifications and projections.

Any idea on how do to this ? thanks :)

Comment: FWIW Spring doesnt generate any query. Your JPA provider does.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that on a projection. Just add the WHERE clause in your query, something like:

```
List<CarProjection> findByColor_Label(String label);
```

It might not add the where clause in the join, but after - applying it to the whole query. But the end result should be the same.

Docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions